# can i standardise a path import file in mysql for different os?

Tags: mysql

I want to import a file from a project with the sql command below in MYSQL where the members of project have a different OS, either Linux/Unix and MS DOS and working from localhost.

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'path_file'
INTO TABLE database.table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';';`

Comment: MS-DOS? I hope you mean Windows. There's no singular path that will work on *every* operating system. Let the user specify which path to import from if you need to handle these sorts of cases. Drive letters, volumes, home directories all vary considerably.

Comment: Yeah i mean Windows. I think too that there's no singular patth. But in Linux there is ~/ that mean user home root directory. And if i can't  find an answer with path, some Third Party program?

Comment: `~/` *might* be their home directory, there's not always guarantees that exists, or that's where they've put the file. I'm not sure what your ultimate goal here is, as database configurations vary *wildly* from even one computer to another. Operating systems add even more wrinkles.